# How do I change x-axis labels on bxp

Tags: r

I am new to R and wondering how would I go about changing the x-axis labels. This is my code:

```
o=c(1,2,3,4,5) # the rows in increasing order
stats.data=list(stats=data.matrix(stats[o,]),n=rep(1,ncol(stats)))
# the n=... parameter doesn't affect the plot, but it still needs to be there
bxp(stats.data,log="y")
```

Currently i see the numbers 1 to 40 at each tick mark. Instead, I would like to be able to put the column headers from my data frame, which looks like this for the first two columns:

```
  Row.Labels    OB          MFD ....
1 Minimum       0.00250 0.0380
2 25 percentile 0.00250 0.0380
3 Median        0.00725 0.0650  
4 75 percentile 0.01200 0.3010
5 Maximum       0.01200 0.3010
6 Mean          0.00725 0.1347
```

So what I would like is for the x axis ticks to read "OB, "MFD",...etc

I don't understand how i can make reference to (and display) that in my code.

Thank you

Comment: `boxplot` is more user-friendly, I think. Is there any chance you can use that instead? what data structure are you working with? (`boxplot` eventually calls `bxp` after some processing)

Comment: @rawr: I've been given the data statistics - not the hard data. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution would be to suppress `bxp` from creating the labels (`show.names = FALSE`) and then just add them in yourself using the return value of `boxplot` or `bxp` as the positions of the labels along the axis.

```
stats <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Row.Labels    OB          MFD
1 Minimum         0.00250 0.0380
2 '25 percentile' 0.00250 0.0380
3 Median          0.00725 0.0650  
4 '75 percentile' 0.01200 0.3010
5 Maximum         0.01200 0.3010
6 Mean            0.00725 0.1347")[, -1]


o=c(1,2,3,4,5) # the rows in increasing order
stats.data=list(stats=data.matrix(stats[o,]),n=rep(1,ncol(stats)))

## make bxp and use the return value (position of boxes on x-axis)
(bp <- bxp(stats.data,log="y", show.names = FALSE))

# [1] 1 2

## use the generic axis function
axis(1, at = bp, labels = names(stats))
```

[image]

If you look under `?boxplot` you will see this example which is using `boxplot` instead. It has a lot more interesting return values. Namely, in your data, you are supplying `stats` and `n`, ie, the first two values of `bx.p`.

Apparently all you need use `bxp` are `stats` and `n` which you have given in `stats.data`

```
set.seed(753)
(bx.p <- boxplot(split(rt(100, 4), gl(5, 20))))
# $stats
# [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
# [1,] -1.66391873 -2.02625162 -2.12785004 -2.76510496 -1.70034047
# [2,] -0.55308292 -0.65897584 -0.86705616 -1.63431484 -0.81848966
# [3,] -0.06763313  0.04887846  0.09674026 -0.06712275 -0.01150075
# [4,]  0.68813940  0.91705734  1.05562526  0.56746581  0.49017934
# [5,]  1.14222667  3.16270157  2.07574986  2.09523462  1.87734641
# 
# $n
# [1] 20 20 20 20 20
# 
# $conf
# [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
# [1,] -0.5061554 -0.5079321 -0.5825407 -0.8450091 -0.4738519
# [2,]  0.3708891  0.6056890  0.7760212  0.7107636  0.4508504
# 
# $out
# [1]  4.115274  3.224584  3.920438  4.168341 -4.357819  2.498006
# 
# $group
# [1] 1 1 1 4 5 5
# 
# $names
# [1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5"
```

So it looks like you could also do something like

```
o=c(1,2,3,4,5) # the rows in increasing order
stats.data=list(stats=data.matrix(stats[o,]),n=rep(1,ncol(stats)), names = names(stats))
# the n=... parameter doesn't affect the plot, but it still needs to be there
bxp(stats.data,log="y")
```

and it should fill in the names for you.

Comment: i appreciate it - i was able to get a little further in my understanding and to do what I wanted.